# Xamarin Forms - How do I implement Max Height functionality?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

`Xamarin Form`s has a `MinimumHeight` property, but no `MaximumHeight` property. Here's my scenario:

Inside a page, I have a `ListView`, which I want to grow to a max of approximately 3 items, and then scroll if it's any taller than that. In the web world, I would simply use a `max-height` property. But in `Xamarin Forms` there's no such property, only a `MinimumHeight` property.

So how do I accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a question from years ago, but I run into this recently which is FlexLayout in a ScrollView. I came up with a goofy solution for it, maybe this can somehow offer a perspective for similar situation.

Essentially, you wrap the entire thing with a StackLayout to be used for setting the maximum height. Then get the height of a single item and set the height of it in code behind based on how many items you have in the list. If you have a child per row, this would be quite simple. In my case, the items are in FlexLayout which can behave quite randomly since they are different in length.

So the structure for the view is:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Wrapper">
    <ScrollView>
        <FlexLayout x:Name="ItemList"
                    SizeChanged="OnItemListSizedChanged">
            // Items
        </FlexLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

In code behind:

```
private double _itemHeight;

private void OnItemListSizedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var childCount = ItemList!.GetChildren().Count;

    switch (childCount)
    {
        case 1:
            _itemHeight= ItemList.Height;
            Wrapper!.HeightRequest = _itemHeight;
            
            break;
        case > 2:
            Wrapper!.HeightRequest = _itemHeight * 2;
            // You can adjust the height accordingly.
            
            break;
        case >= 3:
            Wrapper!.HeightRequest = _itemHeight * 3;
            
            break;
    }
}
```

For delisting items, I used a similar method to link up with

```
public Action OnItemsReduced;
```

to listen when the item count goes down.

```
private void OnItemListSizedReduced(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var childCount = ItemList!.GetChildren().Count;
    
    switch (childCount)
    {
        case 0:
           Wrapper!.HeightRequest = -1;
           ItemList.HeightRequest = -1;
           // Reset the elements, important

           break;
        case 1:
           Wrapper!.HeightRequest = _itemHeight;
                
           break;
        case > 2:
           Wrapper!.HeightRequest = _itemHeight * 2;
                
           break;
        case >= 3:
           Wrapper!.HeightRequest = _itemHeight * 3;
                
           break;
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the latter method to listen the increase of the item list, but it doesn't work very well.